# JQuery mobile- Ajax append with two a href tags is causing a bug in listview

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am calling via ajax that include two tags with this code:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); //Inject data to the cells
                         $('#myPostsList').append('<li class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="listIcon" ><div class="behind"><a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn delete-btn">Delete</a></div><a href="" data-myProfile='+item.myUserProfileID+' data-key='+item.myrandomPostId+'><img class="feedImage" src='+item.myPic+'></img><p><strong>'+item.myName+", "+item.myGender+'</p></strong>'
                                                 + '<p>'+item.myPost+'<p>'

                                                 + '<p class="ui-li-aside" ><time class="timeago" datetime='+item.myTime+'></time></p></a></li>'
                                                 );

                                }

                                });
```

As you can see, there is two anchor tags,`a href="#myPopupDialog"`and `a href=""`. The first anchor is a button that will pup up a window, while the second tag takes you to another page.

The Bug:
When I click the anchor tag to call the pop up window, it takes me to the other page instead. I can see in the console that is linked to the `#myPopupDialog`. Is ther any function to disable one link when another link is clicked and vice-versa?

Comment: What does the CSS for the class behind look like?  Where do you want the delete button to be? Can you get it to work with the plain markup before inserting it via ajax?

Comment: Hi @ezanker. I have this attributes fir the div in css: `.swipe-delete .behind {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;}`. I have disabled `a href=""`so non of the links work now, so I assume that somehow the `a href` is overwriting the delete button anchor tag, because when is active, the I get the same link from both of them, which is `a href=""`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The tags where appended wrongly, so I added '+' between `li`and the `div behind`and at the end of the same div and it is working now.